# Best way to create a secure terminal environment for a multiplayer text based game in python

Tags: python, ssh

I want to create a multiplayer text based game for a fun project. I want to run a python server that responds to a telnet/ssh to my IP. Once the player is connected, they will be able to enter commands to do different things. There will be chatting, ascii graphics, trading, and various other things.

I need a high level networking library that will allow me to do this. Here are my current issues:

1. I would preferably like this server to be asynchronous
2. I want everything to take place through the terminal by either telnet, ssh, or some other built in way of connecting to servers. I don't want the end user to have to install anything like a client or dependency.
3. I would like end to end encryption while the user is connected. This is where a problem arises. My guess is I won't be able to use telnet for this, but I am not sure about SSH. I need users to be able to register and login to their accounts through the terminal, and I want the information the server sends back and forth to the client to be encrypted and illegible by an eavesdropper.

My biggest problem so far is figuring out how I will make this game secure, but run in pure terminal. I also want to use curses to make cool menus and maps with ascii. How would I achieve this? Will I be able to manipulate text with curses on the server side and send it to the client, or does the client need curses installed?

Answer (score 1):

*Network*

You may use `asyncio`: it is built in Py3.4. It implements some kind of event loop with asynchronous io, and allows you to have many clients on one process. Yoy may use http://asyncssh.readthedocs.org/ to implemenet ssh, it is pretty secure

*Curses*

Each terminal (the real one from 70th or terminal emulator like linux console or xterm) has some escape codes which are used to draw pseudo-graphics, clear screen, beep etc. Such codes (terminal capabilities) are stored in `termcap` or `terminfo`, and appropriate terminal type is stored in `$TERM` env variable. Curses use this info to send correct codes to terminal. So, you may use curses here, but usage depends on which client are you going to have.

If you are going to write client on Python, then you may install curses on client machine and use abstraction like "draw menu" in your protocol.
In this case client may be even graphical, since drawing is client's duty.

But if you will use simple ssh client (like Windows Putty) you will need to obtain client's terminal type  (http://asyncssh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#getting-terminal-information) , set it as TERM variable, and then redirect curses output (or stdout if curses use it)

Comment: This helped a good amount. I will look into asyncio and ssh implementation. Thanks.

Comment: I looked into this library and it won't work on my computer. It keeps giving me errors in python3.

Comment: You can create another question with this errors, probably people may help you with them

Answer (score -3):

Consider ssh and Unix Domain Socket binding.

"Unix Domain Sockets can be protected from access by users other than the one who created the port forwarding tunnel. By extension, the connection to the remote host will also be protected from unauthorized access. To support use of Unix Domain Sockets for port forwarding, two options were added to SSH."

Source: https://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/cybersec/corpora/Cybercorpora/README.sshhop

Comment: I dont understand how this helps me.